# Haskell: List Comprehension

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension

I have a function that takes in a list, and if there are 2 identical and successive numbers in the list, and if there is a number, x, elsewhere in the list, that is equivalent, then I want to change x to 0 and return the list.

```
twoAdjThenThirdZero (x:y:xs) = [if x == y && x `elem` xs then 0 else x | x <- xs]
```

For some reason, it is omitting the first two elements in the list every time I try to run it.

```
*Main> twoAdjThenThirdZero [2,3,4,1,2,0,2,3,3]
```

[4,1,2,0,2,0,0]

Also, the above case is doing the opposite of what I would like. I want to keep the two 3's at the end of the list and make the second element, that 3, to be 0. But it was switched around.

```
*Main> twoAdjThenThirdZero [2,2,3,1,2,4]
```

[3,1,0,4]

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because when you use `(x:y:xs)` you're expecting `x` and `y` to be any elements of the list, when in fact, they're just the first two. I din't understand your aim; what would you want as output from `[2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1]`?

Comment: ... and what would you expect as output from `[1,1,1,1]`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! For [2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1], that should become [0,0,0,0,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0]. The number that is isolated should be 0 if there is a pair of that number elsewhere in the list.

Comment: I'm assuming that the list input will not have more than 2 consecutive and identical numbers. Thanks!

Comment: What would you want happen if you have two pairs? Only keep the first one? Eg [2,2,1,2,2]?

Comment: For your next question, please also give examples of what you _would_ like to happen, being as varied as you can.

Comment: By the way this is the second question about making other items in a list zero; what's the underlying task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple problems here. You start by destructuring the parameter list in the function declaration `twoAdjThenThirdZero (x:y:xs)`. If you want to continue to get x and y for each step, you have to recurse. Instead you switch to using a list comprehension, and a duplicate of x. In the list comprehension you go through xs, which is all elements of the function parameter except the first two (x and y).

If you read the list comprehension out loud I think you can figure it out.

"if x equals y and x is an element of xs then zero else x, for every x in xs". But you want it done for every x in x+y+xs! You are also using the name "x" in two ways, both in your destructuring of the function arguments and as a variable in the list comprehension.

EDIT:

Now I see what you mean. You just have to add that explicit recursion to what you have already.

```
twoAdjThenThirdZero [] = []
twoAdjThenThirdZero [x] = [x]
twoAdjThenThirdZero (x:y:xs) 
  | x == y && x `elem` xs = x : y : twoAdjThenThirdZero [if z == x then 0 else z | z <- xs]
  | otherwise             = x : twoAdjThenThirdZero (y:xs)
```

I hope that makes sense to you, if it doesn't, I'll try to explain it further!

EDIT:

phynfo has posted a slightly simpler version of what I was writing!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm looking to get the number that is isolated to become zero, so [2,2,3,2] becomes [2,2,3,0]

Comment: From the example in the comment to the question, it seems he wants to keep `y` too.

Comment: @DanielFischer y should be kept, it's consed to xs in both cases.

Comment: But it's mapped to 0 in the list comprehension, and iiuc, it should be kept with its value.

Comment: Thanks everyone! If I wanted to get rid of numbers before the double, would it work if I make another function and recurse the other way?

Comment: @user1670032 don't think you'd need to, just change things around a bit and use two copies of the original list. But do you want all pairs kept or just one?

Comment: I'm assuming the list will only have one pair. How would I use two copies of the original list? Sorry, I'm new to Haskell:(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
adjToZero = adjToZero' (allDoubles xs) 

adjToZero' ds [] = []
adjToZero' ds [x] = [x]
adjToZero' ds (x:y:xs) = if (x/=y) && (x `elem` ds) then 0:(adjToZero' ds (y:xs))
                                                    else x:(adjToZero' ds (y:xs))

allDoubles [] = []
allDoubles (x:y:xs) = if (x==y) then x:(allDoubles xs)
                                else allDoubles (y:xs)
```

Example:

```
> adjToZero [1,2,1,1]
[0,2,1,1]
```